# JavaScript - typeof Object vs Object()

Tags: javascript, object

```
console.log(typeof Object)    => function
console.log(typeof Object())  => object
```

What is the explanation behind this ?

P.S - I'm a newbie to JavaScript.

Comment: Well, `Object` is a function and calling it, (i.e. `Object()`) returns an object. Don't see what there is to explain? Please elaborate on your question.

Comment: Because it's defined in the specification: http://es5.github.io/#x15.2.1. Maybe the MDN documentation is easier to understand: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object.

Comment: If you're getting confused by the fact that you're getting an instance of `Object` even though you aren't using `new Object`, this is just some behavior the people who came up with the spec added to primitive types (perhaps for convenience). You should not expect all constructor functions to return an instance of themselves if you just invoke them.

Comment: basically, JavaScript gives you an `Object` function; you call it by saying `Object()`; and the return value of this function is an object. Hence calling `typeof` on the function gives you a type of "function", and calling `typeof` on its return value (which is what you get when you do `typeof Object()`) gives you a type of "object".

Comment: Thanks guys, makes perfect sense now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're having trouble grasping the concept of first-class functions. This happens a lot to Java programmers who start programming in JavaScript and expect it to be similar to Java because of the nomenclature. So let me make this clear:

**JavaScript is nothing like Java.**

First class functions are a difficult concept to understand if you've been exposed to too much Java dogma radiation.

The basic idea of first-class functions in JavaScript is that:

**Functions are objects.**

This is a really good thing because it means that we can pass functions as arguments to other functions and return functions from other functions. This allows us to do a lot of cool stuff. For example:

```
function compose(f, g) {
    return function (x) {
        return f(g(x));
    };
}
```

Here the `compose` function takes two other functions as parameters and returns another function which is mathematically equivalent to `f . g`. For example:

```
function thrice(x) {
    return 3 * x;
}

function plusOne(x) {
    return x + 1;
}

var thricePlusOne = compose(plusOne, thrice);
```

This is equivalent to writing:

```
function thricePlusOne(x) {
    return plusOne(thrice(x));
}
```

Once you get the hang of it functional programming will come naturally to you. It's very simple.

Anyway, let's talk about constructors. A constructor is a function which returns an object. For example `Object` is a constructor. Hence:

```
console.log(typeof Object); => function
```

I want you to think of the `typeof` operator as a function. If it helps, you could write it as follows:

```
console.log(typeof(Object)); => function
```

See what we are doing here? We're passing the `typeof` operator a constructor function. Hence `console.log` displays `function`.

On the other hand in the following code `console.log` displays `object`:

```
console.log(typeof Object()); => object
console.log(typeof(Object())); => object
```

The reason this happens is because you're calling `Object` and passing the return value of `Object` to `console.log`. In this case the return value of `Object` is an empty object (i.e. `{}`).

Note however that most constructors in JavaScript only return objects when you prefix the function call with the `new` keyword. This makes JavaScript code look more like Java. However all the native constructors (e.g. `Object`, `Array`, `Function`, `Number`, `String`, `Boolean`, etc.) allow you to omit the `new` keyword. Hence the following two statements are equivalent:

```
console.log(typeof Object()); => object
console.log(typeof new Object); => object
```

This is not usually true for user defined constructors. You can make constructors which allow you to omit `new` but that's beyond the scope of this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Object is simply the name of a function and calling it as it is you're referring to the code of Fuzion (object in a nutshell is just the name of the container), this means that the function is executed.
Writing "object ()" instead're actually performing the function then the amount taken into account by your "if" is not the function itself but the value that the function returns.

Example:

```
 var a = function () {
      return "say hello";
 }

 b = a // -> b is a perfect copy of a (function)*
 c = a() // -> c is the returned string "say hello", if u write d = b () d has same value of c because write a() or b() fire the same function
```

*** is the same if you write:

```
var b = function(){
   return "say hello";
}
```

Whenever you call a function with () javascript solve it, writing the name of the function without () JavaScript will consider the function itself.

example, write:

```
typeof Object() //--> object
```

is the same to write:

```
typeof {} //--> object
```

because javascript solve Object() function and consider the typeof the returned value.

my english suck... sorry.

Answer (score 0):

`Object` is a function because you can call it using `Object()`
However what you do now when using `typeof(Object())` is to call the function `Object()` first, take its return value and get the type of that return value, which is an object in this case.

However when you just call `typeof(Object)` then you don't execute the function Object(), instead you just check what type the variable Object is. And because this variable is a function you can call with `Object()` it tells you that `typeof(Object)` is a function